# Update Html Table after another select | Jquery | Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this Code where i just select two players and i show some stats of those players.
I'm Using Just A regular table to show the data (image1);

My Problem is , after i select another player ,  instead of updating the data from the new player i selected , the table just create another line (image2). all the data that show's are correct , but i dont want it to create another line on the table , i want to erase the past player and update to the current player but i dont know how i can acomplish that.

I'm Not the best with jquery , that's my code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
//The First player Select

            jQuery("#p1").on('focusout', function(e) {

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                var p1 = $('#p1').val();
                var p2 = $('#p2').val();    

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('ajax') }}/?p1=" + p1 + "&p2=" + p2,
                    method: 'Get',

                    success: function(result) {

                        $("#player1").append("<h2 class='p1'>" + result[0].player + "</h2>");
                        $("#p1kills").append("<h2 class='alignRight'>" + result[0].kp + "</h2>");
                        $("#p1kda").append("<h2 class='alignRight'>" + result[0].kda + "</h2>");
                        $("#p1cspm").append("<h2 class='alignRight'>" + result[0].cspm + "</h2>");
                        $("#p1gpm").append("<h2 class='alignRight'>" + result[0].gpm + "</h2>");
                        $("#p1dpm").append("<h2 class='alignRight'>" + result[0].dpm + "</h2>");
       

                    }
                });




            });

//The Second player Select
            jQuery("#p2").on('focusout', function(e) {

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                var p2 = $('#p2').val();
                var p1 = $('#p1').val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('ajax') }}/?p1=" + p1 + "&p2=" + p2,
                    method: 'Get',

                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#player2").append("<h2 class='p1' >" + result[1].player + "</h2>");
                        $("#p2kills").append("<h2 >" + result[1].kp + "</h2>");
                        $("#p2kda").append("<h2 >" + result[1].kda + "</h2>");
                        $("#p2cspm").append("<h2 >" + result[1].cspm + "</h2>");
                        $("#p2gpm").append("<h2 >" + result[1].gpm + "</h2>");
                        $("#p2dpm").append("<h2 >" + result[1].dpm + "</h2>");


                    }
                });




            });

        });


    </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: HI, use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: as simple as it should be , Thanks , It's working !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace this

`.append()`

Into

`.html()`

i hope you got your solution thanks .